# How to remove duplicate entry from array?

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [sectionid] => 4
        [catid] => 148
        [jobid] => 1
        [jobposition] => Bank Staff reuqired
        [skilllevelid] => 1
        [commitmentid] => 1
        [companyname] => Babkers Bank
        [companysizeid] => 1
        [listedbyid] => 1
        [edate] => 2013-05-24 00:00:00
        [educationlevelid] => 1
        [workexpid] => 1
        [iscvrequired] => 0
        [minaed] => 1800.00
        [maxaed] => 2200.00
        [addcompensation] => 250.00
        [description] => Leading bank in your place requires a junior bank staff.
        [question] => Do you know how to find fake notes?
        [correctans] => Yes
        [incorrectans] => No
        [incorrectansop] => May be
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [userid] => 1
        [sectionid] => 4
        [catid] => 148
        [jobid] => 1
        [jobposition] => Bank Staff reuqired
        [skilllevelid] => 1
        [commitmentid] => 1
        [companyname] => Babkers Bank
        [companysizeid] => 1
        [listedbyid] => 1
        [edate] => 2013-05-24 00:00:00
        [educationlevelid] => 2
        [workexpid] => 1
        [iscvrequired] => 0
        [minaed] => 1800.00
        [maxaed] => 2200.00
        [addcompensation] => 250.00
        [description] => Leading bank in your place requires a junior bank staff.
        [question] => Do you know how to find fake notes?
        [correctans] => Yes
        [incorrectans] => No
        [incorrectansop] => May be
    )
)
```

Comment: this crypt code!! why?

Comment: Format your question and make it readable

Comment: try using array_unique

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579749/removing-duplicates-from-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

1. use print_r to output your array readable
2. array_unique returns you an array with no redundant values --> http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: See the comments at the array_unique man page for functions that might work with an array of associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Below is example from php.net manual..

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
The above example will output:
Array
(
[a] => green
[0] => red
[1] => blue
)
```