# remove duplicates from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

print_r($jobtypes) give me an array. Array contains duplicate elements. I want to remove the duplicates. Here is an array

```
                Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 40
            [name] => Babysitting
            [slug] => babysitting
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 40
            [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 43
            [name] => Lawn Mowing
            [slug] => lawn-mowing
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 43
            [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 39
            [name] => Leaf Raking
            [slug] => leaf-raking
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 39
            [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 41
            [name] => Pet Sitting
            [slug] => pet-sitting
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 41
            [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 42
            [name] => Plant Watering
            [slug] => plant-watering
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 42
            [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 2
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 44
            [name] => Snow Shoveling
            [slug] => snow-shoveling
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 44
            [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 5
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 40
            [name] => Babysitting
            [slug] => babysitting
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 40
            [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

How to remove the duplicates. I this case

```
[name] => Babysitting
                [slug] => babysitting
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 40
                [taxonomy] => job_listing_type
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 3
                [filter] => raw
```

is twice. I used

```
$jobtypes= array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $jobtypes)));
```

but not working. thanks

Comment: What is the language? Add tag please.

Comment: Where does the data come from? If it comes from a database then you should write your query so that duplicates are not included in the result. Also, did you [use the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+array+remove+duplicates) before asking? There are plenty of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579749/removing-duplicates-from-an-array) that basically ask the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a manual loop structure looking for the **non**-existence of each `term_id` in a unique array, and if it's not there then add it.

In this example I'm using the `term_id` as the array key for an easy lookup during the loop.

```
$unique = array();
foreach($your_array as $key => $value) {
    // look for non-existance of term_id in $unique array (as key)
    if(!array_key_exists($value->term_id, $unique)) {
        // add to unique array
        $unique[$value->term_id] = $value;
    }
}
```

After you've created an array containing unique objects, you can reset those array keys and assign the unique array back to the original array like this:

```
// reset array keys by assigning values to original array
$your_array = array_values($unique);
```